# "!="/NOT perhaps not working properly in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with about a hundred rows.  It has a column is_gallery that contains either 1, 0, or NULL.  If I do...

```
 SELECT * WHERE is_gallery != 1
```

or

```
 SELECT * WHERE NOT (is_gallery = 1)
```

it excludes the rows where is_gallery is null.  I can manage to get a proper response if I do

```
 SELECT * WHERE (is_gallery = 0 OR is_gallery is null)
```

But shouldn't the "!=" or NOT work?  Isn't there a way to just return the rows where is_gallery doesn't equal 1 without testing for every other possibility?

Comment: `NULL` is special in SQL. Any comparison that uses it is false.

Comment: NULL is not equal to anything, not even NULL, which means you have to explicitly use `IS NULL`  as well. You can use `IFNULL` like this: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ISNULL(is_gallery, 0) <> 1`

Comment: `NULL` is also not "not-equal" to anything.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Almost any comparison results in `NULL`, which is not true.  This is ever so slightly different from being false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`IS` and `IS NOT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot) operators instead of `=` and `!=`. These treat `NULL` like a normal value.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE is_gallery IS NOT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to use is `coalesce` as in:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE coalesce(is_gallery,0) != 1;
```

what `coalesce` does, is replaces any null value in that column with the second parameter. In the example above, any nulls in the "is_gallery" column will be replaced with 0 before it is compared with 1. So will of course return true.

On `NULL` realize that a `NULL` value isn't equal to ANYTHING - not even NULL itself. It cannot be compared - so when "comparing", it always will return FALSE. On NULL, it has a special operator which is `"IS NULL"` or `"IS NOT NULL"`